# IUnknown interface -for COM \COM + objects?

Tags: c#, interface

I am bit unclear in using IUnknown interface. Is IUnknown interface only meant to work with COM /COM + Objects and some unmanaged codes like Win APIs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

COM interfaces are used primarily by unmanaged code.  If you need the C# you are writing to interoperate with unmanaged code, you can export it as COM interfaces:

[COM Interop with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx)

IUnknown is generally the base class for COM objects.

Comment: +1. Just one note, you can scratch the "generally", all COM object must implement IUnknown

Answer (score 2):

In context of C# and .NET - yes. You should [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509(VS.85).aspx) IUnknown only for COM.

Answer (score 2):

IUnknown is a COM/COM+ interface.  Its not used natively by .NET languages such as C#.